# R lattice boxplot grids

Tags: r, lattice

I have data in a form that is similar to the below.  I'd like to create a 4x4 grid of boxplots from it.  However, the below code only produces a single box plot.  When I do xyplot it plots fine.  I'm new to R so I'm sure its a dumb mistake but can anyone help/answer why there is different behavior for xyplot and bwplot and how I can get a 4x4 of the boxplots?

```
library(lattice)
require(lattice)
t1 <- c(LETTERS[1:17])
m1 <- matrix( rnorm(12*16,mean=0,sd=1), 12, 16)
fac <- rep(1:4,3)
    m1 <- cbind(m1,fac)
    m1 <- data.frame(m1)
    colnames(m1) <- t1
    m1$Q <- as.factor(m1$Q)

xyplot(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P ~ Q,
        data=m1,
        groups=A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P,
        scales=list(relation="free"),
        col="blue",
        layout=(c(4,4))
        )
bwplot(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P ~ Q,
        data=m1,
        groups=A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P,
        col="blue",   
        coef=4, do.out = FALSE,
        layout=(c(4,4))
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `outer=TRUE` to `bwplot(...)` seems to do the trick:

```
bwplot(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P ~ Q,
        data=m1,
        groups=A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P,
        col="blue",   
        coef=4, 
        do.out = FALSE,
        outer = TRUE,
        layout=(c(4,4))
        )
```

[image]

From the help file:

> A variation on this feature is when the ‘outer’ argument is
>             set to ‘TRUE’. In that case, the plots are not superposed in
>             each panel, but instead separated into different panels (as
>             if a new conditioning variable had been added).

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the data first:

```
library(reshape)
m1d<-melt(m1,id=17)

bwplot(value ~ Q | variable, data=m1d)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great because if I add more columns to the dataset I don't have to keep adding them to the groups and defining equation!  Really great.  This test dataset was all on the same scale but my real data spans several scales so I needed to also add "scales=list(relation="free")," and set the layout as a 4x4.  Thanks so much for your help.